# operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not accept data type tsvector

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN full_text_vector TSVECTOR;

CREATE INDEX full_text_index ON users USING gin(full_text_vector gin_trgm_ops);
```

The last line is giving me the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR: operator class
>   "gin_trgm_ops" does not accept data type tsvector (SQL: CREATE INDEX
>   full_text_index ON users USING gin(full_text_vector gin_trgm_ops))

Without adding `gin_trgm_ops` to the last line it works, but then I can't search on possible misspellings. Is it possible to both have rankings AND misspelled words?

Comment: It all depends on the details of your undisclosed situation (table definition, Postgres version number, query, description). Just to make sure: you are not, by any chance, confusing *full text search* with *trigram similarity* operations? If you are not sure, consider [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/939860).